# Displaying Qt tree through QAbstractItemModel and QModelIndex

Tags: c++, qt, tree, treeview, qabstractitemmodel

I'm trying to display a user defined tree Family_tree through a TreeModel class derived from QAbstractItemModel containing a Family_tree ft_ member and the overrides for the index, parent, data etc methods.
I rewrote the methods using the Family_tree nodes and I'm calling them from MainWindow like shown below (I double checked Family_tree and it is being set up correctly). All I see is empty space with a single '1' appearing on the top left corner since I have columnCount return 1 for all the nodes and I'm starting by trying to display a tree with only one node (I only expect icons to show up).

Am I misinterpreting how this works in any way? I would really appreciate some insight, thank you for your time!

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    inh_pattern = AD;
    patient = new Patient("Nancy Kalaj", Date(12, 12, 1997), 25, 'F', Genotype("DD"), Date());
    family = new Family_tree(*patient);
    selected = new SelectedPatient(); selected->setSelectedPatient(patient);

    patientOverview = new PatientOverview(*patient, *selected, this); patientOverview->show();
    patientRelatives = new PatientRelatives(*family, *selected, this);
    treeModel = new TreeModel(*family);
    QTreeView* view = new QTreeView(this);
    view->setModel(treeModel);
    //...
}

QModelIndex TreeModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex& parent) const {
    if (!hasIndex(row, column, parent)) {return QModelIndex();}

    node* parentNode;
    if (!parent.isValid()) {parentNode = ft_.get_root();}
    else {parentNode = static_cast<node*>(parent.internalPointer());}

    node* childNode = parentNode->getChildren()[row];
    if (childNode) {return createIndex(row, column, childNode);}
    else {return QModelIndex();}
}

QModelIndex TreeModel::parent(const QModelIndex& index) const {
    if (!index.isValid()) {return QModelIndex();}

    node* n = static_cast<node*>(index.internalPointer());
    node* parentNode = n->getParent();
    if (parentNode == ft_.get_root()) {return QModelIndex();}

    return createIndex(row(parentNode), 0, parentNode);
}

bool TreeModel::hasChildren(const QModelIndex& parent) const {
    if (!parent.isValid()) {
           return true;
       }
       node* n = static_cast<node*>(parent.internalPointer());
       return !n->getChildren().empty();
}

int TreeModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const {
    node* parentNode;
    if (parent.column() > 0) {return 0;}

    if (!parent.isValid()) {parentNode = ft_.get_root();}
    else {parentNode = static_cast<node*>(parent.internalPointer());}

    return parentNode->getChildren().size();
}


int TreeModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const {
    return 1;
}

QVariant TreeModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
    if (!index.isValid()) {return QVariant();}

    node* n = static_cast<node*>(index.internalPointer());
    if (role == Qt::DecorationRole) {
        if (index.column() == 0) {
            QPixmap pixmap(16, 16);
            pixmap.fill(Qt::black);
            QPainter painter(&pixmap);
            painter.setBrush(Qt::white);
            painter.drawRect(0, 0, 15, 15);
            return QIcon(pixmap);
        }
        else {return QVariant();}
    }
    return QVariant();
}

Qt::ItemFlags TreeModel::flags(const QModelIndex& index) const {
    if (!index.isValid()) {return Qt::NoItemFlags;}
    return Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable;
}
```

Comment: You do not seem to return anything what `Qt::DisplayRole` is passed to `data`. Is the `1` you say you can see the table header?

Comment: At first glance, the code you posted in your question is missing mandatory functions: `rowCount` and `columnCount` + `hasChildren`, required for your hierarchy. Please edit your question with these.

Comment: @Atmo I tried including a Qt::DisplayRole case by returning the patient's name and it's still not showing up. I'm not sure what the 1 is, all I know is that if I change the number of columns I hard coded in columnCount to 2 or 3 I see something like 1    |2    |3    so it does look like the table header? It almost seems like data isn't being called at all, which is weird considering that QTreeView should call it automatically for each node(?)

Comment: Does `rowCount` return non-zero values? Was `family` empty all along? Hardcode `rowCount` so it returns 1 and see if it makes the view call `data`.

Comment: rowCount() does return non-zero values, I checked and it returns the size of the std::vector<node*> children member of the node class as it should. I've populated family with just one patient (aka the root) for simplicity and I see that rowCount() returns 0, columnCount() 1, hasChildren() true (need to change it?); then it jumps to index() with parameters 0, 0, and an invalid parent, gets into node* childNode = parentNode->getChildren()[row]; and crashes because getChildren() returns and empty vector of course. I hard coded 1 in rowCount() and unfortunately it still crashes.

Comment: So ... `rowCount()` returns 0? Or not?

Comment: in this case yes because family has only one node; if I add a child to the root node for example it will return 1

Comment: It won't call data if it returns 0. If you force it to 1, do you see data being called?

Comment: I see, I'm trying to force it but it won't even get to data() because it gets stuck on index() and gives a segmentation fault error at the node* childNode = parentNode->getChildren()[row]; line so I'm trying to fix that first somehow

Comment: IMHO, you are not adding a child to `family` like you think you do.

Comment: I am, I always check family through the debugger and the node pointers look right. i think I’m going to adopt a simpler approach here and just use QStandardItemModel and QStandardItem to make a tree view.. thank you so much regardless!

Comment: If you are not able to fix `node* childNode = parentNode->getChildren()[row];`, you won't manage to use `QStandardItemModel` either. I was not commenting if your pointers were right, I was commenting that I do not see where you add a children into the `getChildren()` vector/list of the `family` variable.